# Trying to switch 0 for 1 in the end of the function but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

i am having problem witht his code.

in the end of the function i am trying to switch 1 for 0 or 0 for 1;

this button should after each click change the words for Hello or stop clicking me;

big thanks in advance

```
function MediaDropDown()
{
    var hello="hello";
    var stopClicking="Stop Clicking Me";

    var notClicked=1;

        if(notClicked < 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("mediaArea").innerHTML=hello;

        }
        if(notClicked > 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("mediaArea").innerHTML=stopClicking;

        }

        ChangePolarity();
}

function ChangePolarity()
{
    if(notClicked<1)
        {
            notClicked=1;
        }
    if(notClicked>0)
        {
            notClicked=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: notClicked is defined in the MediaDropDown function and u are using it in ChangePolarity function its out of scope

Comment: Put the variable notClicked outside of the function i.e. make it a global variable.

Comment: thanks guys :) i am just learning.  big thanks

Comment: FYI, you can reduce your `ChangePolarity` to `notClicked=+!notClicked;`. The `!` converts the number to a negated boolean value, so `1` becomes `false` or `0` becomes `true`. Then the `+` converts it back to a number, so `false` becomes `0` or `true` becomes `1`.

Comment: Please take the time to at least write some capital letters in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `notClicked` variable is non-persistent; every time you run the MediaDropDown function it is being redefined and set to 1 so you will always see the text "stop clicking".

Move it outside of the function so that it retains its value.

```
var notClicked=1;

function MediaDropDown()
{
    var hello="hello";
    var stopClicking="Stop Clicking Me";
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 var notClicked=1;

 function MediaDropDown()
 {
var hello="hello";
var stopClicking="Stop Clicking Me";



    if(notClicked < 1)
    {
        alert(notClicked);

    }
    if(notClicked > 0)
    {
         alert(notClicked);
    }

    ChangePolarity();
 }

 function ChangePolarity()
 {
if(notClicked<1)
    {
        notClicked=1;
    }
if(notClicked>0)
    {
        notClicked=0;
    }
 }
```